# Touring a chess board with multiple pieces [Python]

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, knights-tour

I have been trying to solve this for 2 days straight and I just can't find a valid algorithm. Given a Chess board, and a number of pieces, I have to check if said board can be toured by the pieces, with the condition that each piece can only visit an square once. I know it's some kind of multiple backtracking, but I can't get it to work. (I only have been able to implement a general knight's tour for individual pieces)

`tablero` is a class of the board, that holds a name, a list of pieces, a list with prohibited positions, a list with the free positions, and a tuple with the dimensions of the board.

`ficha` is the class of a piece, it holds a name (`nombre`), a tuple with its position (`posicion`), a list with its valid movements (`movimientos`) (For example, a pawn's list would be [ [0,1] ], meaning it can only move forward 1)

Any insight is welcome.

Here are the classes (Feel free to add/remove any method).

```
def legal(pos,dimensiones):
    if pos[0] >= 0 and pos[0] < dimensiones[0] and pos[1] >= 0 and pos[1] < dimensiones[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False


class board:

    def __init__(self,name,pieces,dimention,prohibited_positions):
        self.name = name
        self.pieces = pieces
        self.dimention = dimention
        self.prohibited_positions = prohibited_positions
        self.free_positions = []
        for x in range(dimention[0]):
            for y in range(dimention[1]):
                self.free_positions.append([x,y])
        for x,y in self.prohibited_positions:
            if [x,y] in self.free_positions:
                self.free_positions.remove([x,y])
        for piece in self.pieces:
            if self.piece.position in self.free_positions:
                self.free_positions.remove(piece.position)


    def append(self,piece):
        pos = piece.position
        if pos in self.free_positions:
            self.pieces.append(piece)
            self.free_positions.remove(pos)



class piece:

    def __init__(self,name,position,move_offsets):  
        self.name=name
        self.position=position
        self.move_offsets=move_offsets
        self.possible_movements=move_offsets

    def setPos(self,pos):
        self.position=pos

    def ValidMovements(self,dim,free_positions,prohibited_positions):
        aux = []
        for i in self.possible_movements:
            newX = self.position[0] + i[0]
            newY = self.position[1] + i[1]
            newPos = [newX,newY]
            if legal(newPos,dim):
            aux.append(newPos)
        for i in list(aux):
            if i not in free_positions:
                aux.remove(i)
```

Comment: It's difficult to debug in foreign langage. Also without knowing how you use this makes it impossible to know what doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean "toured by the pieces"? Also, are the pieces specified? Also, since you also speak English, could you translate your code for us? It would make debugging much easier.

Comment: Okay, give me some minutes.

Comment: By toured, i mean that all of the empty squares of the boards are visited once , with the condition that only 1 piece can visit an square.

Comment: Do Queens, Bishops and Rooks visit the squares they pass through if they make a multi-square move? E.g. if a Bishop moved from `(1,1)` to `(3,3)`, would `(2,2)` be considered visited? Would that be a legal move if `(2,2)` had already been visited by another piece?

Comment: No 2,2 would not be considered visited. And it may be considered legal or ilegal, it isn´t spicified in the problem.